# Typescript dynamic filter array based on value entered

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a requirement that to filter the arrays of objects based on the value entered in input fields.
**Data**

```
data: [{
  taskname: 'Test1',
  taskId: '1',
  status: 'Submitted'
}, {
  taskname: 'Test2',
  taskId: '2',
  status: 'Resolved'
}, {
  taskname: 'Test3',
  taskId: '4',
  status: 'Submitted'
}, {
  taskname: 'Test4',
  taskId: '5',
  status: 'In Progress'
}, {
  taskname: 'Test5',
  taskId: '6',
  status: 'Resolved'
}, {
  taskname: 'Test6',
  taskId: '7',
  status: 'Submitted'
}
}]
```

in the input field, while entering

> R

Then i have filter data based on  status value with "R"
Respected o/p

```
data: [{
      taskname: 'Test2',
      taskId: '2',
      status: 'Resolved'
    }, {
      taskname: 'Test5',
      taskId: '6',
      status: 'Resolved'
    }
    }]
```

My code

```
var o/p = data.filter(x => x.status == input filed value);
```

The above code is not working properly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post some code for your html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let filterdData = data.filter(x => x.status.includes(input))`

You can use [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to return the subset of data whose `status` property includes your `input`